# Specifying data type for EXT-JS form elements

Tags: forms, extjs

Can someone please tell me how to specify the data type for the EXT-JS 4.2 form elements. For example, in a form , if I have a "salary" field, I expect it to send it as a long value to server after form submission. 
As of now, when I do ,

```
Ext.getCmp("someId").getValue()
```

I am always getting string representation of what I have entered in the salary field. For example, if I enter 5000 in the salary field I receive "5000" as a value instead of 5000.
Thanks
Samir

Comment: You might want to use [numberfield](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number) xtype.

Comment: or just cast the value with 'parseInt'

Comment: Ahh ok . I did not realize that earlier :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the ExtJS version you've using, you can look at the docs for [numberfield](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-method-getValue) xtype. `getValue()` method of that component, as per documentation returns,

> Returns the current data value of the field. The type of value returned is particular to the type of the particular field (e.g. a Date object for Ext.form.field.Date), as the result of calling rawToValue on the field's processed String value.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: This server my purpose. Thank you everyone for the help.